# Copy .js and compile .coffee during Makefile task

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, makefile

I have a node project with:

- `.coffeescript` source in **src**
- compiled coffeescript output to **lib**
- shell scripts in **bin**

How can I adjust my `Makefile`, shown below, to also copy `.js` files in **src** to the **lib** directory?

```
BIN = ./node_modules/.bin
SRC = $(wildcard src/*.coffee)
LIB = $(SRC:src/%.coffee=lib/%.js)

init:
    npm install

clean:
    @rm -r -f $(LIB)

build: $(LIB)

dist: clean init build

lib/%.js: src/%.coffee
    $(call coffeetime)

define coffeetime
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(BIN)/coffee -bcp $< > $@
endef
```

Also, if you have any other suggestions to improve the Makefile, please share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this might work.

- Add `SRCJS = $(wildcard src/*.js)`
- Change `LIB = $(SRC:src/%.coffee=lib/%.js)` to `LIB = $(SRC:src/%.coffee=lib/%.js) $(SRCJS:src/%=lib/%)`.
- Add:

  ```
  lib/%.js: src/%.js
      @cp $< $@
  ```

If it doesn't work (for some reason) then you may need to use a static pattern rule but I think something like the above should work.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you to use Grunt instead.
There is a few neat task that handle Coffeescript compiling very well. Like: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee

Also, depending on your needs, Node.js can cope with Coffeescript directly if needed.

Comment: I like the idea, but the Makefile does the job and works well for my coworkers. I may delegate work to Grunt down the road, though.